# Change RadioButtonColor using code pre API 21

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

In my application I create `RadioButtons` dynamically using code.

```
    RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(context);
    radioGroup.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    RadioButton yesRadioButton = new RadioButton(context);
    yesRadioButton.setText("Metallic");
    yesRadioButton.setTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(0xFF5A5A5A));
    yesRadioButton.setTextSize(18);
    yesRadioButton.setPadding(0, 0, 180, 0);
```

I wish to set the color of the actual button (the cirlce) to a specific color: #ED7C02. I have tried using the line of code `yesRadioButton.setButtonTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(0xFFED7C02));` and this works when the device is API 21 (Lollipop). When I try it on a device which runs an older API then I get the following stack trace:

```
09-28 08:15:15.131  14184-14184/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: za.co.gpsts.gpsjobcard, PID: 14184
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.RadioButton.setButtonTintList
```

Is there a different way to achieve this? My app uses a dark background and as a result the black is very hard to see.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use selector for Radio Button, this works with all android versions

Create a selector drawable for you radio button under drawable/radio_button.xml folder and mention all the required states for your radio button.

And add this property android:button="@drawable/radio_button" for your radio button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
 android:state_checked="true"
 android:state_window_focused="false"
 android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button_on" />
<item
 android:state_checked="false"
 android:state_window_focused="false"
 android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button_off" />
<item 
 android:state_checked="true" 
 android:state_pressed="true"
 android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button_on_pressed" />
<item
 android:state_checked="false" 
 android:state_pressed="true"
 android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button_off_pressed" />
<item
 android:state_checked="true"
 android:state_focused="true"
 android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button_on_selected" />
 <item
  android:state_checked="false"
  android:state_focused="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button_off_selected" />
<item
 android:state_checked="true"
 android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button_on" />
<item
 android:state_checked="false"
 android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button_off" />
</selector>
```